# Google Drive Video Player C++/CLI

Tags: c++-cli

I'm a new C++ Programmer , and I'm working on a project for a C++ windows application for Online watching .
so i searched for 3 hours about how to open Video's uploaded on Google Drive on my app but i found nothing . and YouTube works fine with Shockwave Flash object as :

> axShockwaveFlash1->Movie = "https://www.youtube.com/v/htdfIopZ38o";

i was asking if there any method to use GD Player in my program 
and sorry for my bad English. 
thanks

Comment: Can't you embed the WebView? You have the WebBrowser component accessible both in WinForms and in WPF.

Comment: i tryed it but there is some thing wrong the site open but the video don't start at all